# Async function printing empty var

Tags: javascript

I want to call a function and return a value from another function the problem is that the value is empty

```
async function Print(){
  var result = await readFile();
  console.log(result);
}
async function readFile() {
  const FileName = ['g.png','g2.png'];
  const Files = FileName.length;
  texts = '';

  FileName.forEach( async function(FileName) {
     Tesseract.recognize(FileName,'ara',{ logger: m => console.log(m) }).then(({ data: { text } }) => {
     texts += text;
     console.log(texts);
})});
return texts;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the following implementation using `for of` loop should work. Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37576787/14953535) for more information.

```js
async function readFile() {
  const FileName = ['g.png','g2.png'];
  const Files = FileName.length;
  let texts = '';
  
  for (fName of FileName){
    const { data: { text } } = await Tesseract.recognize(fName,'ara',{ logger: m => console.log(m)});
    texts += text;
    console.log(texts);
  }
  return texts;
}
```